# Вопрос по приложению на Ionic Framework

Tags: ionic, ionicframework

Новичок в этом деле, пару вопросов для профессионалов думаю не составит труда ответить.

1. Как отключить начальную заставку в приложении? Пробовал в config.xml менять значения, но при последующей компиляции значения возвращаются на дефолтные.
2. Как оживить кнопку "Позвонить"?
   Пробую так:
   Добавил в AndroidManifest.xml строку `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`, в шаблоне использую
   `<a class="button button-block icon-left ion-ios7-telephone button-positive" ng-href="tel: 89140662934">Позвонить</a>`, через браузер пытается звонить, из приложения - молчит.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Отключить заставку - your_project/config.xml:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="0"/>
```

2) Подключить библиотеку ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser, ссылки писать такого вида:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('tel: 89149990001');">Позвонить</a>
```